# Windows 10 boot menu after Linux Mint

Tags: windows-10, boot, linux-mint

I was using Linux Mint in addition to Windows 10 ,my primary OS. After deleting Linux Mint I saw that Linux Mint is still shown as an option on Windows boot menu.Probably I didn't remove Linux properly. I just deleted the disk partition it was installed on.Now, how can I remove Linux Mint from the boot menu so the laptop boots directly to Windows as it used to do?
Thanks..

Comment: Can you able to boot linux still?

Comment: You can delete the linux partition and check.

Comment: No I can't boot into linux, as I already  deleted linux partitions as you said. But I still see Linux Mint option in the start up. If I choose it, it takes me to a DOS screen which says error:no such partition entering rescue mode....etc.....  I just want the Windows Boot manager to disappear and windows start when I turn on the laptop.